# Event Study - receive error message even with the packages sample data

Tags: r

I am trying to run event studys in R. Unfortunately there is just one package in R which contains the featurtes I need.

To do this, I use the package "EventStudy".

```
http://127.0.0.1:20476/help/library/EventStudy/doc/addin_eventstudy.R
http://127.0.0.1:20476/help/library/EventStudy/doc/howto_eventstudy.R
http://127.0.0.1:20476/help/library/EventStudy/doc/introduction_eventstudy.R
http://127.0.0.1:20476/help/library/EventStudy/doc/parameters_eventstudy.R
```

Until last Wednesday it worked as shown in the description. Now I get strange error warnings. This happens even with the sample data from the package.

Does anybody know what the message means as well as how to solve it?

The error message is:

```
> EventStudy:::EventStudyAddin()
Loading required package: shiny

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5750
[1] "Validate input files."
[1] "Perform Event Study"
[1] "Check batch process: Step 0"
Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'http_error' applied 
to an object of class "data.frame"
77: httr::http_error
76: self$getTaskStatus
75: estAPI$performEventStudy
74: observeEventHandler
 3: shiny::runApp
 2: runGadget
 1: EventStudy:::EventStudyAddin
```

This is ran by the EventStudy API.

Does anybody know whats ment by the error message? How do I solve this? I despair of it!

Comment: Issue has been reoslved in version 0.35 please see below:
https://github.com/EventStudyTools/api-wrapper.r/issues/8#issuecomment-468842777